# Visual Studio - An exception was encountered while constructing the content of this frame

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework

I am trying to open a solution on VIsual Studio 2017. (The project was originally developped in VS 2012). I managed to open the project and to work on it before. But this morning I get :

> An exception was encountered while constructing the content of this frame. This information is also logged in "C:\Users\myName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_fa6f4449\ActivityLog.xml

The project loads in VS, but it does not recognized the Entity Framework Models correctly. Any idea on what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For further reference (maybe it'll help someone in the future), I have solved this error by updating Visual Studio. It was apparently an IDE bug. (More info [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/30312/problems-when-starting-vs-2017-enterprise-on-windo.html))